# Count Laravel cron execution

Tags: laravel, cron

I have Created Queue in laravel and using php artisan queue:work to run the queue everything is working fine.

I just want to change some value in middle of cron execution For example if there are 100 Jobs Scheduled then after 10 Jobs execution want to change some value.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information, it's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I have setup the cron jobs and the detail are being store in the Jobs table in laravel (around 100 jobs is there). after executing the 10 Jobs via cron I want to terminate the execution of jobs.

Comment: Then I can't help but wonder why you scheduled 100 jobs.